# Reset an ES6 module with SystemJS (for unit tests)?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, systemjs

Our workflow includes using ES6 modules. This also includes unit tests. We `import` modules under test. The problem is that the original authors decided to have every module return objects, and so we have global singletons (because of how ES6 imports work) all throughout the code base---a classic unit testing problem.

Is there a way to "reset" said modules with SystemJS after each test?

sample unit test (loaded by karma-systemjs):

```
import MUT from './Mut' // module under test

describe('MUT', () => {

   it('should do stuff', () => {

      MUT.value = 'foo'
   })

   it('should do more stuff', () => {

      // value should not be 'foo' here. How do you reset MUT?
   })
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this issue](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/366) on Github, and particularly [this comment](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/366#issuecomment-180057616).

Try deleting and then re-importing the module in a `beforeEach` block like so:

```
describe('MUT', () => {

  let MUT;

  beforeEach((done) => {
    // remove the previous version
    System.delete(System.normalizeSync('./Mut'))
    // re-import the module
    System.import('./Mut').then((imported) => {
      MUT = imported
    }).then(done, fail)
  })

  it('should do stuff, () => {
    MUT.value = 'foo'
    expect(MUT.value).toBe('foo')
  })

  it('should do more stuff', () => {
    expect(MUT.value).not.toBe('foo')
  })

})
```

Comment: yea i think we tried that. The problem is Mut's dependencies also need to be reloaded